¿Cómo conectar una base de datos local a una base de datos en el servidor en la creación de una aplicación desktop?
Tengo el siguiente el problema, soy nuevo con lo de las bases de datos y lo que quiero es crear un login y registro de usuario en una aplicación de escritorio que estoy creando con python y tkinter, no se que código exactamente debo escribir para que esos datos del login y registro se vayan a una base de datos en el servidor al momento de ya haber creado y distribuido el ejecutable de la aplicación. esto con el fin de digamos como ejemplo si alguien instala su aplicación en Estados Unidos y otra persona en España ambos datos de los registros lleguen a mi base de datos central que esta en el servidor. He estado investigando y no encuentro mucho o no he sabido buscar bien, encuentro cosas de ssh y tuneling pero no se exactamente si realiza de esa forma y no logro entender bien, dejo un código sencillo abajo con la intención de si alguien me podría hacer el favor de corregirme o ayudarme a estructurarlo mejor, muchas gracias.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Función para conectarse a la base de datos remota
def connect_to_remote_db():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='remote_host',      # Cambia esto por la IP o el hostname de tu servidor
            database='remote_db',    # Nombre de la base de datos en el servidor remoto
            user='remote_user',      # Usuario de la base de datos remota
            password='remote_password'  # Contraseña del usuario de la base de datos remota
        )
        if connection.is_connected():
            db_info = connection.get_server_info()
            print("Conectado a la base de datos MySQL versión", db_info)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select database();")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print("Conectado a la base de datos", record)
            return connection
    except Error as e:
        print("Error al conectar a MySQL", e)
        return None

# Función para conectarse a la base de datos local
def connect_to_local_db(local_host, local_user, local_password, local_db):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=local_host,
            database=local_db,
            user=local_user,
            password=local_password
        )
        if connection.is_connected():
            db_info = connection.get_server_info()
            print("Conectado a la base de datos MySQL local versión", db_info)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select database();")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print("Conectado a la base de datos local", record)
            return connection
    except Error as e:
        print("Error al conectar a MySQL local", e)
        return None

# Función para validar el inicio de sesión
def login():
    username = entry_username.get()
    password = entry_password.get()

    # Aquí puedes agregar la lógica para validar el usuario y la contraseña
    # Por simplicidad, vamos a asumir que si el usuario es "admin" y la contraseña es "password", el inicio de sesión es exitoso
    if username == "admin" and password == "password":
        messagebox.showinfo("Login exitoso", "Bienvenido, " + username)
        root.destroy()  # Cerrar la ventana de login

        # Conectar a la base de datos remota y local (ejemplo)
        remote_connection = connect_to_remote_db()
        local_connection = connect_to_local_db('localhost', 'local_user', 'local_password', 'local_db')

        # Aquí puedes agregar la lógica para interactuar con las bases de datos conectadas
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Login fallido", "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos")

# Crear la interfaz de inicio de sesión con Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sistema de Inicio de Sesión")

tk.Label(root, text="Nombre de usuario").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Contraseña").grid(row=1)

entry_username = tk.Entry(root)
entry_password = tk.Entry(root, show="*")

entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(root, text="Iniciar sesión", command=login).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

root.mainloop()

